# Editing java.security - says it is [read only] (Fedora)

Tags: linux, permissions, java

I am trying to edit the file java.security but it opens as read only.  I am running as root user but I think this is happening because the java process is currently using the file.

How can I temporarily close the process and edit the file and then start java up again?  I am using Fedora.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or it could, in fact, be read-only. You can use `:w!` to attempt to change the permissions to allow writes, write the file, then restore the permissions.

Comment: haha...it looks like you are in fact correct, cheers.